# Copy file to host before container stops running

Tags: docker, pytest, pytest-cov

I'm running a Flask app in a docker container, linking it with a postgres container, and testing using pytest. If I run the command

```
docker run -it --env-file=.env --link postgres-test app pytest --cov=service . --cov-report html:cov_html
```

my tests run, and I get to see the output, but how do I copy the coverage directory `cov_html` before this container stops running? I want to be able to view the coverage report as html in my browser.

My current workaround is terribly hacky, `docker run -it --env-file=.env --link postgres-test app bash`, then running the `pytest` directly in the container and while the container is still running I `docker cp` to a local directory.

I'd much rather just run something like the original command and when pytest finished the local directory is overwritten with the latest coverage report, so a browser refresh should be all I need to do to view changes.

Comment: You'll wanna use a volume

Comment: I’d just run `pytest` directly on the host in my development virtual environment.  Why do you want Docker here?

Comment: @DavidMaze imagine you have integration tests that require some service to be set up. You 1. don't want to install and configure it on your dev machine and 2. can often use a prepared container image with everything preinstalled.

Comment: Mounting tests dir in a volume is also something I use, e.g. set `WORKDIR /io` in the Dockerfile, then `docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/io my/tests /bin/pytest` will mount current dir to `/io` and every file `pytest` writes in container will be written to current dir.

Comment: If you will create the appropriate user in the Dockerfile, you can even match the hosts's user so you don't get files written as root, e.g. `docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/io --user $(id -nu):$(id -g) my/tests /bin/pytest`

Answer (score 1):

Hi with docker you can write a custom ENTRYPOINT and use a volume so that once your test is done the end of the entry point script will copy over the cov_html to the area with the volume. Something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

#command to run tests

cp /location_to/cov_html /location_to/volume
```